# How to use both color and image as background with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, background, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use a background color (say blue) for my screen, and an image (to add effect) too in addition to color. How do I do it?

Currently I'm doing:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)) {
.
.
.
.
.
}
```

But in 'background' there is no option to specify Image.
How do I do this?

Comment: You could add an Image inside the Box. Do you want an image with a gradient over the image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background)) {
  Image(
      painter = painterResource(R.drawable.header),
      contentDescription = null,
      modifier = Modifier
           .fillMaxSize(),
      contentScale = // Your contentscale
  )
}
```